# Shortest way to call possibly undefined function

Tags: typescript, optional-chaining

Coming from a background in C# the null-conditional operator allows you to call a function avoiding a possible null-reference exception like so:

```cs
Func<int> someFunc = null;
int? someInteger = someFunc?.Invoke();
// someInteger == null
```

Given that Typescript has the "optional chaining operator" `.?` with very similar functionality I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same with a similarly concise piece of code. The best I can come up with is using a conditional expression:

```
let someFunc: (() => number) | undefined = undefined;
let someNumber = someFunc !== undefined ? someFunc() : undefined;
```

Perhaps [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) can be utilized somehow?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Conditional invocation is possible in Typescript. Introduced in 3.7 as **optional chaining**.

```
const a = () => {console.log('hey')}
const b = null
a?.()
b?.()
```

The linter might complain but it complies and runs, [see this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAFASiQPhgb1JEAGwFMA6QkAcxQHIALYgTxrQF8BYAKH2hgCMkMMAFdChLnAD8pdFz7T0QA)

Read more about it in this [blog](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/optional-chaining-the-operator-in-typescript) or in the [offical docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

Comment: I must have stared myself blind to not see that in the documentation. My linter seems to accept it - at least for now. Thanks!